# error message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, asp.net

The following code is generating an error:

```
else if (period.ToString().Equals("3 years"))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 36; i++)
        {
            string strCommandText5 = "INSERT INTO AutoTrans VALUES(@loanID,@transPeriod,null,@transStatus);";

            SqlCommand myCommand5 = new SqlCommand(strCommandText5, myConnection);
            myCommand5.Parameters.AddWithValue("@loanID", Session["@loanID"].ToString());
            myCommand5.Parameters.AddWithValue("@transPeriod", numPeriod);
            myCommand5.Parameters.AddWithValue("@transStatus", status);

            numPeriod++;
            myCommand5.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
```

Error message:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object. on myCommand5.Parameters.AddWithValue("@loanID", Session["@loanID"].ToString());

Please help me thanks

Comment: Check whether Session["@loanID"] is null

Comment: Assuming that in your case `Session["@loanID"]` should never be null: you have some errors in your code that leads to `Session["@loanID"] = null`

Comment: is your connection open ?

Answer (score 0):

Change your code as follow

```
else if (period.ToString().Equals("3 years")&&Session["@loanID"]!=null)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= 36; i++)
    {
        string strCommandText5 = "INSERT INTO AutoTrans VALUES(@loanID,@transPeriod,null,@transStatus);";

        SqlCommand myCommand5 = new SqlCommand(strCommandText5, myConnection);
        myCommand5.Parameters.AddWithValue("@loanID", Session["@loanID"].ToString());
        myCommand5.Parameters.AddWithValue("@transPeriod", numPeriod);
        myCommand5.Parameters.AddWithValue("@transStatus", status);

        numPeriod++;
        myCommand5.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Session["@loanID"] is null, check the value in de session:

```
if (Session["@loanID"] == null) { throw new Exception("Session["@loanID"] is null"); } 
myCommand5.Parameters.AddWithValue("@loanID", Session["@loanID"].ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

error is self explanatory, your `session` is empty or null that's why exception is being generated. Use this to send a DbNull if you want to

```
myCommand5.Parameters.AddWithValue("@loanID", Session["@loanID"].ToString() ?? (object)DBNull.Value);
```